# How to resolve failure to open ssr report builder in edge browser with authentication error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Failing to open SSRS report builder on the browser. Its returning an error "Cannot retrieve application. Authentication error"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your windows credentials are being used rather than your SSRS credentials.

To fix this you need to add an entry of your SSRS credentials in the Manage Network Passwords section of your User Account Control Panel.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error @OliverCross1208

Answer (score 0):

Did you able to fix it now. If not, is your ssrs server configured to use windows credentials? Then, are you trying to access the server using ip from another machine.

If accessing using ip. add the computer name and ip in your host file. Change the custom report builder url to use server computer name.